# Is the algebra of adjointable operators on a Hilbert module prime?

Tags: operator-algebras, banach-algebras, hilbert-modules

In abstract algebra, a nonzero ring $R$ is a prime ring if for any two elements $a$ and $b$ of R, $arb = 0$ for all $r$ in $R$ implies that either $a = 0$ or $b = 0.$  Or for any two ideals $A$ and $B$ of $R$, $AB=\{0\}$ implies $A=\{0\}$ or $B=\{0\}.$

Let $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the set of all adjointable operators on Hilbert module $E$, if $\mathcal{L}(E)$ prime algebra?

($E$ is Hilbert module over $\mathcal{K}(H)$, such that $\mathcal{K}(H)$ is the set of all compact operators on Hilbert space $H$.)

Comment: Your question is "if $L(E)$ prime algebra"?

Comment: Ok, it is. Is the proof similar to proof of B(H)?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the answer to the original version of the question:

What do you assume on $E$? If nothing then the answer is trivially **no**.

Let $E=\mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}\oplus \mathbb{C}$ be the three-dimensional abelian C*-algebra regarded as a Hilbert module over itself. Then $\mathcal{L}(E)\cong E$ as the algebra of adjointable operators on a C*-algebra is nothing but the multiplier algebra. As $E$ is unital we do not get anything new. Certainly, for any $r\in E$ we have $$(1,0,0)\cdot (0,0,1)=(0,0,0) = (1,0,0)\cdot r \cdot (0,0,1).$$

Comment: $E$ is Hilbert module over $\mathcal{K}(H)$, such that $\mathcal{K}(H)$ is the set of all compact operators on Hilbert space $H$.

Comment: Please pay attention to: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and assume that $K=H\oplus H$, so $K$ is a Hilbert space and $\mathcal{B}(K)\cong \mathcal{B}(H)\oplus\mathcal{B}(H)$, but we khnow that $\mathcal{B}(K)$ is prime!!!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Pay attention to above statement, please. With respect to your answer, $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K})$ is not prime, but we khnow that $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{K})$ is prime!!!

Comment: Also, in my question, $E$ is a Hilbert module over $\mathcal{K}(H)$.

Comment: @Alireza, I do not understand your objections. I do not make any claims about $\mathbb{B}(\mathcal{K})$. I am only saying that the algebra of adjointable operators over any unital non-prime algebra (regarded as a module over itself) is not prime.

In your original question, the Hilbert module was completely arbitrary.

Comment: I had edited my question, where $E$ is not arbitrary Hilbert module.

Comment: Then you should've asked a separate question.

Comment: Can you answer to the edited question?

Comment: This answering is true for special Hilbert module. Is true for general?